# Snap to face with project individual elements giving weird results

Tags: topology, snapping

I've seen several duplicates of similar questions to mine already but none of them have the same problem as me. Im following the donut tutorial for blender 3.0 and am at the stage where I have to make the icing. while im able to find and turn on snap to faces and project individual elements, Trying to grab and move the topology results in a weird output where it kinda sucks into the donut. please help.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. If anyone's having similar issues, check if snapping is turned on and/or if there's another mesh under the mesh you're trying to edit.